# PCI Compliance + embedding iframes + security risks

Tags: apache, security, x-frame-options, pci-compliance

I'm working on a website that needs to set `Content-Security-Policy` headers to disallow the site from being embedded via iframes. This was a result of a recent PCI audit. However, there is one single endpoint that we need to make embeddable via iframes. This endpoint exposes a video player.

The solution we've come up with is this:

1. Disallow embedding for all pages
2. Allow embedding for the player page

Apache vhost file:

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self';"

<Location /video-player/index.php>
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors %{HTTP_REFERER}e;"
</Location>
```

## Questions

1. Are there security risks in using the `%{HTTP_REFERER}e` string directly on the header?
2. Is there a way to sanitize that value within Apache?
3. Is there a better way to special case just that one URL? Unfortunately, we can't just use a wildcard because the browser will ignore the header if one is used.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use:

```
Header add Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; frame-ancestors 'self';"

<Location /video-player/index.php>
    Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"
</Location>
```

Comment: Because you can't use a wildcard for the frame ancestors value. You must specify an actual domain name for it.

Comment: That works, but may not be strict enough from a PCI point of view. Good idea, though

Comment: It's exactly the same risk as checking referrer, so should be fine for PCI purposes assuming that the framed page does not have elements that an attacker could exploit for clickjacking.